# Migration of the wordpress from Azure to windows instance of AWS?

Tags: wordpress, iis, azure, amazon-web-services

I'm currently hosting the wordpress using the Azure IIS mysql for my blog and would like to move to the Amazon web services (AWS) windows instance.
Does anyone know how to migrate properly I have read plenty of sites but it seems to be more focused on linux

Regards,

Comment: What's the reason why you're looking to move? I might be able to help you with issues you are having on Azure, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Your Mysql is a cleardb instance. You must connect to it using MySQL Workbench and export data.

You can do the same with wordpress through wp-admin